# pwa-studio docker configuration dev-environmet

Tags: docker, magento2, progressive-web-apps

In order to work with pwa-studio I have to use docker due to the fact that I am using windows. So I made it in the simplest possible way for me with Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
```

then I created container:

```
winpty docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/app nfr:1.0 bash
```

all commands related to installation packages or running app I make being attached to container

Using address localhost:3000 I can see my app running since I expose the port.

PROBLEM:
One of the first configuration steps in pwa-studio is to add a custom hostname and SSL cert, which is done with

```
yarn buildpack create-custom-origin ./
```

As a result app inside container is no longer available via localhost:3000 but via domain name, in my case it is: https://pwa-aynbv.local.pwadev:3000/

How to configure docker to expose this domain outside of the container ?

Thanks in advance for any help